# percentage of certain msgs in an hash table

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, find, percentage

I'm looking for an algorithm that will help me accomplish this:
I need to write a program in C that will get unknown number of msgs from senders to receivers.
Like 23 to 12, 44 to 19 etc' and i need to return all the senders\receivers that are responsible for over 10% of the msgs. I'm allowed to use an hash table.

Thanks

Comment: So go ahead and try to write it... But seriously please read FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)  about asking questions. You are currently asking us to write it for you. What have you done so far?

Comment: I'm trying, but i need something that works :) I'm very new to hash to be honest.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."... And to answer your question it would require a few chapters of C for beginners book.

Comment: @bcelary, I assume he only wants the algorithm, and is going to program it himself.

Comment: @ugoren, ah, haven't realized.

Comment: @Mika Stern, could you please rephrase your question so it says you need an algorithm? Could you be more specific about the input of the program? I understand that will be a list of some sort which will also contain a status of the transmission, right?

Comment: Ok, just did. The input would be a sender, a receiver and a msg. Something like: 4 to 6 hello. You are right but from the assignment i didn't understand that there will be any statues of the transmission.I know how to implement this in arrays for say but not with hash, therefor the article in the answer is good but not that helpful. Sorry you miss understood me, i just wanted a lead.

Comment: My idea was something like (total occurance of msg using hash value of msg (in Hash table )) * 100 / (total number of msg in Hash Table.) .. but i'm not sure i'm write and not sure how to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/datamining2011aFiles/ASimpleAlgorithmForFindingFrequentElementsInStreamsAndBags.pdf) describes an algorithm for this.
It doesn't use hash tables, just a simple array of 10 entries (because 10% = 1/10).
It isn't 100% accurate - it will surely find those that use 10%, but may also find some which use less than this.

A quick description of the algorithm:

1. Maintain a list of 10 items plus counters. Initially the list is empty.
2. For every item in the input, if it's in the list, increment the count.
3. If not, add it to the list, with count 1.
4. If this addition makes the list longer than 10, decrement the count for all elements in the list, and delete those which went down to 0. It's assured that the list will return to size 10 or less.